# Asterisk in parenthesis in Objective-C... What does it mean?

Tags: objective-c

Just a quick question from an Objective-C beginner: what does the asterisk in the parenthesis mean in the following sample code? Is it a pointer? Thanks in advance.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Tire : NSObject
@end
@implementation Tire

- (NSString *) description
{
   return (@"I am a tire.");
}

@end
```

Comment: As someone who knows null about Objective-C what does the @ mean in front of the string? Is this similar to C#'s @"" ?

Comment: The @-symbol indicates a compiler directive, in this case, it defines a constant NSString object.

Answer (score 8):

You are correct. The * means that description returns a pointer to an NSString object.

Comment: I would add that you always use pointers in this manner with any Cocoa object.