# Why do we have to put an asterisk on method parameter types in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm starting out Objective-C and I was wondering, why do we have to put asterisks in the method parameter type?

e.g.

```
- (void)myMethodThatTakesAString:(NSString*)string;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asterisk in parenthesis in Objective-C... What does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514139/asterisk-in-parenthesis-in-objective-c-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The asterisk means that the parameter is a pointer to an NSString. You can't pass an NSString to a method, but rather you pass a pointer to it.

Although you might get away with simply using pointers when you have objects and not really understanding them, it's probably a good idea to prioritize learning about pointers.

Comment: So, I am passing a pointer of type NSString as the argument? Is that what you are saying? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because that is what you are passing- a pointer - a memory location or reference to `NSString`.

The notation for pointer, the `*` comes from C.