# objective c method asterisk

Tags: objective-c, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asterisk in parenthesis in Objective-C… What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514139/asterisk-in-parenthesis-in-objective-c-what-does-it-mean)

does anyone can find some resource or detail explanation about following code

```
-(void) add:(Cal *)c;
```

I am very new to obj-c.what does asterisk means in that code?

Thanks.

Comment: dup of [Asterisk in parenthesis in Objective-C... What does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514139/asterisk-in-parenthesis-in-objective-c-what-does-it-mean) and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+%2Bmethod+%2Basterisk).

Comment: A pointer just like in C

Comment: oh,I see tho asterisk means return to Cal ?

Comment: if the code like this 'Cal *myCal', is that 'myCal' point to 'Cal' class?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the argument for the method is a **pointer** to an instance of a "Cal" object.